# ghost blog and mailchimp integration

Tags: mailchimp, ghost-blog

I am trying to integrate some ghost blog articles within a mailchimp nesletter but havent worked it out.

Has anybody done some attempts to integrate a ghost blog content with newsletters sent through mailchimp?

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the Mailchimp embedded form code inside Ghost Markdown post editor and it's suppose to show up just fine. Markdow can be sometimes sensitive about whitespace when it interprets what's html code and what's normal MD, so be aware and keep the code indented...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the mailchimp RSS campaigns instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is actually pretty easy once you figure out the white-space & indentation issues that Michael lists above. For myself, the following steps works:

- Copy the embed form code from MailChimp
- Paste the code wherever you would like in the article (i put mine at the very bottom of the article)
- Indent (use TAB key once) the entire block of code code contained in the `<div id="mc_embed_signup">` section. From `<div id="mc_embed_signup">` to the closing `</div>` just above `<script type='text/javascript' src='//......>`

When you're done you should see the preview pane look like this: (Note: forced to delete picture because I don't have enough points yet...). But look at this link: [Imgur link of valid Mailchimp Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwVbN.png)

Note that there may actually be two or more blocks labeled "Embedded Javascript". That is fine. They won't show up when viewing the post. You just have to make sure that no normal `code blocks` are showing in the preview pane. `Code blocks` are a sign that you may have missed some code that needs to be indented. The properly indented code will trigger markdown properly and prevent it from being show as plain text (visible text) in the post.